# Uniformly bounded and Convergence subsequence

Tags: uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of real valued continuous function on $(0,\infty)$ such that $f_n(x) = f_n(2x)$ for all $x$ for all $n$. Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly bounded can we conclude that $\{f_n\}$ has a uniformly converging subsequence?

Any such function $f_n$ is defined by its value in the interval $[1,2]$. I have tried to construct an example contradicting this statement. But I could not process further. Kindly give some hints.

Thank you.

Comment: Try construction $f_n$ having a peak at $1+\frac{1}{n}$ and decreasing to $0$ elsewhere very fast, such that at $\frac{1}{n\pm 1}$ it's already $0$. You'll then obtain a sequence $f_n$ whose point-wise limit is $0$, and whose convergence is not uniform.

Comment: @Learning Thank you. I can understand your idea. But how to make sure that such a function satisfies $f_n(x) = f_n(2x)$?

Comment: As you said, the function is determined by its value on the interval $[1,2]$, therefore as long as you construct such a sequence of continuous $f_n$ on $[1,2]$ with $f_n(1)=f_n(2)$, it defines a sequence $f_n$ on $(0,\infty)$ which satisfies the condition.
A more geometric way to think of it is that $(0,\infty)/\times 2$ is a circle, no different from $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, via the function $\log$.

Comment: @Learning Thank you. What is the meaning of the notation $(0,\infty)/ \times 2$ ?

Comment: Also, We are trying to define $f_n$ only on $[1,2]$ then why do we need to worry about $\frac{1}{n \pm 1}$. I am not getting this point. Please explain.

Comment: 1. Excuse me, it means $(0,\infty)/G$ as a (topological-Lie) quotient group, with $G$ being the group of integer power of $2$. 2. Indeed, $\frac{1}{n\pm 1}$ is not the only choice. All we need is a bounded sequence with no convergent subsequence. In order to make sure that no subsequence converges, I deliberately let $f_n$ be $1$ in its own domain, and zero elsewhere, and my choice for $f_n$'s domain is $(1+\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n-1})$ (so the notation $\frac{1}{1\pm n}$ was also misleading). As long as these domains are distinct, it's ok.